# SQL Wildcard instead of key in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, wildcard

Can I, in a neat way do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE * LIKE '%something%';
```

Without having to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE ColA LIKE '%something%' 
   OR ColB LIKE '%something%' ...;
```

Running SQL Server 2008, I get error:

> "Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view
>   'tablename' because it is not full-text indexed.

I don't have full text index :)

Comment: Wait... so you want to check if every column in the table is matches that string?? I don't think it really makes sense since the data types of all your columns may be different...

Comment: That's probably not possible (too risky with different column types to make this available in a DBMS) but there is probably a flaw somewhere in your design. Assuming you cannot change the schema, can you not generate the query ?

Comment: @NWest I'm aware of the differences and i was hoping that the db engine would skip/figure out a way to handle the differences.

Comment: @dystroy I can't change the database in any way, i have about 70 tables with all kinds of information and i was hoping for a generic search function that would fit them all without having to define the query, since defining the column names would require at least 1-2 extra querys for each table query, and that could potentially be really slow.

Comment: If your table is big, the slow operation is the search. A few queries to fetch the structure of the table in order to automatically build the search query would be very fast (but maybe painful to write, I don't know how MS SQL Server describes its structure).

Comment: @Torxed, is this a one-time or manual DBA-run thing, or does this need to go into an app allowing users to do this? Also, do you want to search all tables or a specific one?

Comment: @TimLehner This is a query that will be run through a webinterface allowing multiple users to do the query. I understand that this is not ideal but it would speed up things, note: The users are IT personel only so the people accessing the webinterface is trusted users, but again, it's users :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on @Bob Probst's idea, you might try [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#EXEC4) like this:

```
-- Set these!
declare @tableName nvarchar(128)= 'MyTableName'
declare @searchString nvarchar(max)= '%something%'

-- Build SQL query
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = isnull(@sql + 'or ', 'select * from ' + @tableName + ' where ' )
    + '[' + column_name + '] like ''' + replace(@searchString, '''', '''''') + ''' '
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @tableName
    -- Could use this where clause for only comparing string fields (or eliminating image and such)
    --and data_type in ('varchar', 'char','nvarchar', 'nchar')

-- Run SQL query
print (@sql) -- For debug
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: I'll check this out when i get back into the office but looks promesing, i had some issues with declaring variables tho, something about "local variables" can not be assigned if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: You sir, are a genius!

The only wrong you did, was that you can't assign default values in MsSQL, but solving that was just as easy as copying your code, moved down the **= 'MyTableName'** a row.

Comment: @Torxed, You can assign a value as part of a variable declaration starting in [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could script it like this:

```
select 'select * from dbo.ACCOUNT_DIMENSION where '
union all
select c.name+' like ''%something%'' or '
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on (t.object_id=c.object_id)
where t.name = 'ACCOUNT_DIMENSION'
union all
select '1=1'
```

Comment: This is PERFECT! except for one thing, i understand most of the logic however it generates rows as the result and the rows is not matches, it's a perfect search string that i would like to use,
So how do i use this godlike search string that your example generates? (inside SQL), i could use this to generate a search string without a doubt but can i put this straight into a query?

Comment: @Torxed, I've posted a solution that does just that. Thanks to Bob Probst for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. You have to write the fieldnames.

Comment: Figures, would be neat since SQL would probably handle the checks internally faster then PHP/Python can go retrieve, parse through and return the data :/ a ANY variable would be handy SELECT * FROM table WHERE ANY LIKE '%x%'  :)
The -1 is not me, just for the record :P

Answer (score 0):

How's [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142488.aspx)* sound?

```
Use AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Name, Color FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS((Name, Color), 'Red');
```

*This requires fulltext indices

Comment: That works, IF you define all the column names, which i don't want to do because it's supposed to be a dynamic function for all tables across the database WITHOUT having to loop through field names, define a new search based on those returns and then query again :P

And i don't want to cache the table columns/data because it changes to often :)

Comment: It does accept `*` for the column.  It also requires setting up full-text search, which comes with its own assortment of, um, features.  And it doesn't do simple pattern matching.

Comment: @RafaelColucci So? That's not invalid SQL. It's not an incorrect answer. The OP may or may not have full text indices, we don't know that information.

Comment: OK, agreed. But you should specify that you solution needs to use full text indexes. Update your answer and I will revert the -1.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the + sign to bind ColA and ColB together:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   tablename 
WHERE 
   ColA+ColB Like '%something%'
```

Comment: It's by faar the best solution now i think, since i don't have full-text search, but then again i'm trying NOT to write column names since it's supposed to be a dynamic function that can work across tables without having to know the column names.

Comment: And that wouldn't give the expected result.

Comment: True, it would not generate the result i was looking for.
This example would force me to build a search query for each of the ~70 table names in the database instead of having one dynamic search function for all of them.

Comment: Not sure if you can do a wildcard search on each table and each column. Not to mention how slow that would be if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without a fulltext index the only way to do this dynamically is with a dynamically built statement;

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select * from tablename where 1=0'

select @sql += ' or ' + quotename(column_name) + ' like ''%something%'''
from information_schema.columns
where TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
and data_type in ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')

exec(@sql)
```